# Gridview bulk update, best way to detect modified fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

What would be the best way to detect fields that has been modified in a bulk update grid view.

I'm currently retriving all data from database and comparing them to the submited one. But I would love to know a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [GridView's events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than updating all records at once at the end. Events you could use for your update tasks are

```
GridView.RowEditing 
GridView.RowUpdating
```

See the [examples in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Matt doston has provided best way to bulk update in gridview.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx

Another approach is bulk update with datasource

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26973/Bulk-Edit-with-GridView-without-xxxDataSource-SqlD

And third option is the same you are using comparing data. 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)